# How to put a class in the p tag automatically added by the_content() in the wordpress loop?

Tags: php

I tried with this code

```php
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    echo '<section id="depoimentos" class="container-fluid pwp-testmonials">';
        echo '<div class="pwp-testimonials-slider">';
            echo '<h2 class="pwp-testmonials-slider__title pwp-upper-title text-center">O que falam de mim?</h2>';
                if($query->have_posts()) :
                    echo '<img class="d-flex m-auto" src=" ' . TEMPLATE . '/assets/images/avatar.png' . ' " width="150" height="150" alt="avatar"/>';
                        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                            the_title('<h3 class="pwp-testmonials-slider__name text-center">','</h3>');
                            echo '<p class="pwp-testmonials-slider__desc_depoimento text-center">' . the_content() . '</p>';
                        endwhile;    
                else :
                        echo '<h3 class="text-center pwp-testmonials-slider__notice">Nenhum depoimento cadastrado ainda!</h3>';
                endif;
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</section> <!-- end .pwp-testmonials -->';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [`wpautop()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/), which adds the `<p>` tags, doesn't have any way to filter the `<p>` tags it adds.

If you're trying to replace *all* the `<p>` tags in the content with your `<p class="{...}">`, though, you should be able to use the [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse412742_class_up_the_paragraphs' );
/**
 * Adds classes to all the <p> tags in the content.
 *
 * @param  string $content The post content.
 * @return string          The post content with the classes added to the <p> tags.
 */
function wpse412742_class_up_the_paragraphs( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace(
        '<p>',
        '<p class="pwp-testmonials-slider__desc_depoimento text-center">',
        $content
    );
    return $content;
}
```